# Variadic template wrapping function call

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-macros

I need a macro/templated function that will wrap function call of some method on specific object, i.e

```
a.Destroy()
```

where a can be of any type as well as Destroy and Destroy may or may not take 0 to n parameters. Inside this wrapper I need to do some checks.

I would like to be able to call this function as a wrapper:

```
DESTROY_CHECK(a.Destroy(p1,p2,...))
```

or

```
DESTROY_CHECK(a, Destroy(p1,p2,...))
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you post a real usage example? I assume you don't mean to pass a literal ellipsis to the function call?

Comment: Can you use C++11?

Comment: Yes I can, I would prefer using c+11 features over macros

Answer (score 0):

You can consider [variadic macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace):

> ```
> #define identifier( parameters, ... ) replacement-list
> ```
>
> ... defines a function-like macro with variable number of arguments. The additional arguments can be accessed using `__VA_ARGS__` identifier, which is then replaced with arguments, supplied with the identifier to be replaced.

```
#define DESTROY_CHECK(x, ...) assert(x.Destroy(__VA_ARGS__))
```